# Como alocar dinamicamente uma matriz utilizando um ponteiro de ponteiro em uma função void

Tags: c, ponteiro

Estou tentando alocar de foram dinâmica uma matriz em uma função `void`, dessa enviando como parâmetro um ponteiro de ponteiro `int **sigma`, da seguinte forma `lerArquivo(char *alfabeto, int *Q, int *Q0, int *F, int ***sigma, FILE *arq);`, porém estou tendo dificuldade em alocar o espaço de memória na função. Estou enviando o parâmetro de forma errado por ser ponteiro de ponteiro ou estou só errando no momento da alocação de memória?

Grato desde já.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int buscaArquivo(FILE **arq);
void lerArquivo(char *alfabeto, int *Q, int *Q0, int *F, int ***sigma, FILE *arq);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char alfabeto[10], **palavras;
    int Q, Q0, F, T, z, i; 
    FILE *arq;  
    int **sigma;



    if(buscaArquivo(&arq) == 0){
        lerArquivo(alfabeto, &Q, &Q0, &F, &sigma, arq);
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        for(z=0; z< Q; z++){
            printf("teste");
            for(i=0; i< strlen(alfabeto); i++){
                printf("%d ",sigma[z][z]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else
        printf("Arquivo não encontrado!");


    return 0;
}


int buscaArquivo(FILE **arq){

    char nome[50];

    printf("Nome do arquivo: ");
    scanf("%s", nome);

    *arq = (fopen(nome,"r"));

    if(*arq == NULL)
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;   
}

void lerArquivo(char *alfabeto, int *Q, int *Q0, int *F, int ***sigma, FILE *arq){

    int i, j,x, y, z, N, T, tm;

    fscanf(arq,"%s", alfabeto);
    fscanf(arq,"%d", &(*Q));
    fscanf(arq,"%d", &(*Q0));
    fscanf(arq,"%d", &(*F));
    fscanf(arq,"%d", &N);
    tm = strlen(alfabeto);



    //Alocao da matriz sigma
    **sigma = (int****) malloc(*Q * sizeof(int***));
    for(z=0; z< *Q; z++){
        **sigma[z] = (int**) malloc(tm * sizeof(int*));
        for(i=0; i<tm; i++){
            sigma[z][i]=0;
            printf("%d ",sigma[z][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olhando para os avisos do compilador vemos que faltou incluir a biblioteca `<string.h>` que é onde está declarado do `strlen`.

Analisando um pouco as alocações de memoria que fez:

```
void lerArquivo(char *alfabeto, int *Q, int *Q0, int *F, int ***sigma, FILE *arq){
    ...
    //Alocao da matriz sigma
    **sigma = (int****) malloc(*Q * sizeof(int***));
```

Se `sigma` é um duplo ponteiro passado pelo main, fazer `**sigma = algo` não fará sentido. E menos sentido fará capturar um ponteiro em 4º nível num ponteiro de 2º nível. Ponteiro de 4 nívelº pois é o *cast* que está a fazer com:

```
(int****)
```

Logo o que está a procura é algo como:

```
*sigma = (int**) malloc(*Q * sizeof(int*));
```

Repare que estou a guardar no apontado por `sigma` (um `int**`) o resultado de alocação de um array de `int*` ou seja um `int**`. Pode sempre tentar olhar apenas para os tipos que tem de cada lado e ver se jogam:

```
*sigma = int** //olhando apenas para o tipo da direita
*(int***) = int** //colocando o tipo de sigma
int** = int** //resolvendo os parentesis da esquerda
```

Comment: desculpe, tinha editado o código para poder fazer a pergunta aqui, e por acidente a chamada da função não foi editada.

Comment: @jaojpaulo Se é esse o caso tudo o que eu disse à exceção da primeira parte do erro continua válido. Já editei a resposta retirando o que não se aplica.

Comment: ok, obrigado pela explicação mesmo assim.

Comment: da forma que vc explicou quando eu for alocar uma matriz com esse ponteiro duplo eu faria dessa forma certo  **sigma[i] = (int*) malloc(tm * sizeof(int));

Comment: @jaojpaulo Na verdade depende um pouco. No seu exemplo na parte da alocação `sigma` é um ponteiro triplo, e como tem que modificar o que tem no main tem de alocar como `*sigma = (int**) malloc (...`. Caso seja uma alocação de um ponteiro duplo normal então seria `ponteiro_duplo = (int**) malloc(...`

Comment: È pq estou na verdade tentando mandar esse ponteiro duplo para alocar uma matriz